# Bind IFrame SRC to VueJS Data

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, iframe, input

> Can I change the value of an **input** to the **src** of an **iframe**. Is this possible with VueJS
>   I am picturing:

```
<input id="input"/>
<iframe src="welcome.html"></iframe>

let vm = new Vue ({
  data: {
    src: "welcome.html",
  }, 
});
document.getElementById("input").value = /* src from vm.data? */
```

Comment: You should probably use [Vue's ref](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) to access the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
Vue.component('base-iframe', {
  data: function() {
    return {
      url: 'https://example.com'
    }
  },
  template: '<iframe :src="url" />'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#components-demo'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="components-demo">
  <base-iframe />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this helped but it didn't work for what I was trying

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do something like:

```html
<input id="input"/>
<iframe :src="iframeSrc"></iframe>

let vm = new Vue ({
  data: {
    iframeSrc: "welcome.html",
  }, 
});
```

But you need to bind Vue to some parent element, like `<div id="app"></div>`

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped